# How to put "new line" in JSP's Expression Language?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, el

What would be right EL expression in JSP to have a new line or HTML's `<br/>`?
Here's my code that doesn't work and render with '\n' in text.

```
<af:outputText value="#{msg.TCW_SELECT_PART_ANALYSIS}\n#{msg.TCW_SELECT_PART_ANALYSIS2}"/>
```

Comment: You probably want to use <br/>

Comment: I added the "jsf" tag, assuming it from the <af: prefix. Remove it if I'm wrong

Comment: @Bozho: it's the Oracle ADF faces, so you're right.

Comment: yes, I assumed ADF, but who knows what prefixes could one configure for custom tag libraries :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you want to output `<br />`, just do:

```
<af:outputText value="#{msg.TCW_SELECT_PART_ANALYSIS}<br />#{msg.TCW_SELECT_PART_ANALYSIS2}" escape="false" />
```

The attribute `escape="false"` is there to avoid the `<br />` being HTML-escaped.

You can even display the two messages in separate tags and put the `<br />` in plain text between them.

```
<af:outputText value="#{msg.TCW_SELECT_PART_ANALYSIS}" />
<br />
<af:outputText value="#{msg.TCW_SELECT_PART_ANALYSIS2}" />
```

If you're still on JSF 1.1 or older, then you need to wrap plain HTML in `<f:verbatim>` like:

```
<f:verbatim><br /></f:verbatim>
```

Comment: where do I put these <af:outputText... things? Like I have a jsp file, where do they go?

Answer (score 5):

If you want a new line in the browser then you need to put "`<br/>`" in the text. The browser will then interpret it correctly. It does not understand \n.

Comment: This is the best answer!

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
<af:outputText value="#{msg.TCW_SELECT_PART_ANALYSIS}"/>
<af:outputText value="#{msg.TCW_SELECT_PART_ANALYSIS2}"/>
```

(i.e. split the value and put the character you want between the two)?

Answer (score 1):

Write a custom function that calls this piece of code:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public final class CRLFToHTML {

    public String process(final String text) {

        if (text == null) {
            return null;
        }

        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(text, "\r\n", true);

        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String token = st.nextToken();

            if (token.equals("\n")) {
                html.append("<br/>");
            } else if (token.equals("\r")) {    
                // Do nothing    
            } else {    
                html.append(token);    
            }
        }

        return html.toString();

    }

}
```

Comment: This exist already in flavor of JSTL `fn:replace`. Besides, that's also not needed if you use `escape="false"` in `UIOutput` as pointed by Bozho.

Answer (score 0):

use `</br>` instead of /n

ie. inside double quotes "" its allowed to use `</br>`

eg.

```
<af:outputText value="#{msg.TCW_SELECT_PART_ANALYSIS}</br>{msg.TCW_SELECT_PART_ANALYSIS2}"/>
```