# how to add new line break spring <form:error> for the error passed from java code

Tags: java, spring

I am  trying to pass new line break with error message from server code to show up in UI. I am displaying these error message with spring's `<form:error>`

**server code**:

```
error= "xyz"+" \n"+"abc"
```

I want something like this in **UI**:

```
xyz
```

`abc` (in new line)

Comment: What about using `<br />` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing "\n" with "
" is the quick solution. However, I would caution taking such a simplistic approach as your error messages will look strange if ever used in a non-web environment. For example, if you log the error message to a file, it will show 
 instead of a line break.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908365/how-to-put-new-line-in-jsps-expression-language) answer, if you're using some jsp technology, look for the `escape` or `htmlEscape` kinda attributes. And set them to `false`.

For me I was trying to validate a form with `org.springframework.validation.Validator`, and was struggling to render a line break in the html code when an email is not valid.

```
if (!emailId.matches("^.+@.+\\..+$")) {    
    errors.rejectValue("emailId", "error.emailId", "Email ID cannot be blank<br>Should be proper email ID format");
}
```

After setting `htmlEscape="false"`, it worked!

```
<td>
    Email ID
</td>
<td>
    <form:input type="email" path="emailId" id="emailId" />
</td>
<td>
    <form:errors path="emailId" />
</td>
```

I know this answer may be inappropriate for the problem I tried to provide a solution. But, as I couldn't find a exact solution for the issue I was facing, I thought it'd be okay to send it here.