# multiline in shortdesc tooltip in adf inputText

Tags: java, jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I want to display the whole password requirements in the *shortdesc* attribute of *Inputtext*. But every time I pass a String, it is displaying the text in the same row.
For example I am attaching the code with 'hello world' as *shortdesc*.Below is the screen for the same:

[image]

I want 'hello' in one line and 'world' in another line.Can it be done?If yes, Can anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put "new line" in JSP's Expression Language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908365/how-to-put-new-line-in-jsps-expression-language)

Answer (score 0):

The only way that have worked for me is editing the proper underlying css class of the "shortDesc component" (`AFNoteWindowShortDesc`) in the skin file and reading the value with the breakline character from a managed bean if you want to control where to break each line:

In my css-skin file:

```
.AFNoteWindowShortDesc {
    white-space: pre; /* To produce the line break */
}
```

In a managed bean:

```
private String multilineText = "Hello\nWorld";

public String getMultilineText() {
    return multilineText;
}
```

Finally in the page fragment:

```
<af:inputText label="Multiline shortDesc in ADF" id="it1"
                  shortDesc="#{pageFlowScope.departmentManagedBean.multilineText}"/>
```

Result:

[image]

But if your `shortDesc` text is long and you only want it break automatically, then do this:

Skin file:

```
.AFNoteWindowShortDesc {
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @Phani Please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score -1):

It can be done by adding `escape="false"` and a `<br/>` in the middle of your shortDesc.

```
<af:inputText label="label" id="dc_it1" shortDesc="hello &lt;br /> world" escape="false"/>
```

The `escape=false` allow the `<br/>` to not being HTML-escaped.

For more info see: [How to put "new line" in JSP's Expression Language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908365/how-to-put-new-line-in-jsps-expression-language)

Comment: _"Attribute escape not defined on element af:inputText"_