# '\n' is not working.(in jsp/java). How do you represent line breaks?

Tags: java, jsp

```
<% String b="a\na"; %>
<%=b%>
```

When the above code is printed, it is displayed as'a a'.

How do you represent line breaks?

Comment: does this answer your question[How to put “new line” in JSP's Expression Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908365/how-to-put-new-line-in-jsps-expression-language)?

Comment: JSP creates HTML. Linebreaks in HTML are usually ignored unless they are in a special tag like `<pre>` and can be created with the tag `<br>`. You might want to look up a basic HTML tutorial and look up how HTML is used to format elements before starting to work with JSP.

Comment: @XO56 If you hit the "Flag" button under the question and select it to be a duplicate of that question, it will automatically insert that comment for you. (Like mine above.) And it also pushes this question into a review queue where people can vote to close it as an duplicate.

Comment: @Ivar Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enter a linebreak in JSP you need to use <br/> instead of \n for it to show in the browser.